# I keep getting and error message in Pycharm: pyplot error

Tags: matplotlib, pycharm

I keep this error in Pycharm when I try downloading the pyplot library. I'm on the latest version of Pycharm. Anyone know why this is happening?

"Error occured when installing package pyplot"

I haven't had any problems installing any other packages with pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

`pyplot` comes with `matplotlib`, e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

There's not much sense trying to install it separately - [pyplot on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyplot/1.5.0) is only a placeholder.